# Can I display a textview that overlaps it's parent ViewGroup

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, android-view, textview

I have a horizontalScrollView with a listview in it. I add multiple custom RelativeLayouts to this, each one contains two TextViews, vertically.

The top TextView will always be visible and will have a small amount of text, things like S,M,L,XL,XXL.

The bottom TextView will only display when the top one is selected. The text in this will be much bigger though, e.g. Low in Stock, Out of Stock etc.

Because the bottom TextView is bigger, it is forcing the gap between each RelativeLayout to be different depending on the text in the bottom TextView.

I would like the distance to be equal between each RelativeLayout and as there will only ever be one bottom TextView visible at one time, I would like that text to potentially span beneath multiple top TextViews.

Is this possible? At the moment, I can't find anything that will help.

I have included an image. The top is what I have, with the bottom TextView size dictating the overall space. The bottom image is what I'd like, with the bottom Text overflowing beneath the top Text when it needs to.

[image]

UPDATE: @mikejonesguy, roughly what I have is (psuedocode)

```
<Relative Layout>
    <TextView 
      android:id="@+id/id1"/>
    <TextView
      android:layout_below="@id/id1"/>
</Relative Layout>
```

Comment: You can overlay UI elements with FrameLayouts... but what would happen in your case if IT58, IT60 and IT62 all have "Low Stock?" Wouldn't you then overwrite the warnings? Considering using an icon instead.

Comment: Please post your layout xml files, or the relevant code if you're creating these views programmatically.

Comment: @323go Yes they would overwrite but only one "low stock" warning would ever be visible at one time so they wouldn't clash, unless you are thinking of something else?

Comment: @mikejonesguy unfortunately the code is at work and it's now the weekend. I'll give some xml on Monday. However, I'm 99% certain that what I have you can't print outside so I was hoping/expecting for something new, rather than a modification to what I have. Roughly what I have is 
    <Relative Layout>
        <TextView/>
        <TextView/>
    </Relative Layout>

Comment: So I've had to admit defeat with this, but thanks for helping guys.